# How to get correct coords(event.getX() / event.getY()) of Object with OnTouchListener

Tags: android, bitmap, coordinates, ontouchlistener, magnify

I have this :
[image: source case]

and what i want exactly is that to show portion of Bitmap via **coords**(X,Y) of object with OnTouchListener(orange **square** with dot in center).

So the problem is that i want to draw portion of image like it shows on image(Red square "**Area that i want**" to show).
So in this case,excepted result is(portion of bitmap) :
[image: excepted result]
At current moment i'm doing like this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap,view.getX() - view.getWidth(),view.getY()-view.getHeight(),250,250);
            //other stuff to fill this portion of bitmap
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
}
```

And it's not correct.

how can i achieve this?
Tried a lot of formulas,but no luck. Any suggestions?

PS As i understand **event.getX()**/**event.getY()** is getting relative coords(and it's not clear for me,what exactly coords getting from object of imageview with touch listener(orange square with dot in center),i mean its getting **center** of this objects or **Top.Left** corners(X,Y)) ?

Comment: any code samples? I think getY() is inverted in this instance IIRC this may cause you an issue?

Comment: @Hughzi Okay,ill add now code snippets. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: If you log your `event.getX()/event.getY()`, what do you get ?

Comment: @DanChaltiel i'm getting coords of object. Or what you mean?

Comment: @VetaLio I think you need to do getWidth - getX as if you have a width of 100 and you touch 50 currently your drawing at -50?

Comment: @Hughzi yes,for this case i need to recalculate my values. It depends when object is located.

Comment: @VetaLio surely width >= getX in every case? what is teh result you get at the moment?

Comment: @VetLio infact i think you just need getX - (an arbritary) offset (if you want a square) and then the getY value will likley need inverting which is height - getY() then your offsets

Comment: @Hughzi didn't implement yet,but main idea is to check,if getX - width <=0 ,then i recalculate current X coords,via Value = getX - width; Then  createBitmap(sourceBitmap,getX()+Math.abs(Value),getY(),250-Math.abs(Value),250);  And other area to fill with color of framelayout. Something like this.

Comment: @Hughzi how to get this offset value? I need to calculate somehow,but how?

Comment: it would be whatever you want the size of you new square to be. best way would be as a % of H and W - that gives you some consistency across screen sizes?

Comment: @Hughzi an example please,because didn't understood what you mean about consistency across screen sizes :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was simple to resolve this problem.
**Solution**:
I have an object(**orange square**) with OnTouchListener(for e.g. he's an quad with size 50dp **Height**/ 50dp **Width**).
So **view.getX()/view.getY()** takes relative coords(center) of object(that have OnTouchListener).
So what i needed:

```
//imageview parameters ,where i will show this part of bitmap
int Width = img.getWidth();
int Height = img.getHeight();
//after this,i make margin of my coords,via this simple formula -> Current Coord X - Width / 2 (same for Y)
 Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceBitmap,view.getX() - Width / 2,view.getY()-Height / 2,Width,Height);
```

And that is all.
Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, whilst looking in more detail coming up with solution i think i found it and I am at work so can you try this:

Use `event.getX()` not `view.getX()`. the `view.getX()` returns position of the view you are touching not the touch event you are interested in.

This is the Y coordinate which will likely be inverted.

so `event.getX()` is the position of the touch event.

`event.getY()` is the inverted Y position so `getHeight() - event.getY()` will give you the Y position you are after.

**EDIT**

In the case of MOTION_MOVE getX and getY return the most recent and maintains historical data. i guess the most recent one is the most valuable as that's where you will be drawing.

In that case use batching quote from documentation:

Batching - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html

> For efficiency, motion events with ACTION_MOVE may batch together
>   multiple movement samples within a single object. The most current
>   pointer coordinates are available using getX(int) and getY(int).
>   Earlier coordinates within the batch are accessed using
>   getHistoricalX(int, int) and getHistoricalY(int, int). The coordinates
>   are "historical" only insofar as they are older than the current
>   coordinates in the batch; however, they are still distinct from any
>   other coordinates reported in prior motion events. To process all
>   coordinates in the batch in time order, first consume the historical
>   coordinates then consume the current coordinates.

Comment: yes,but i'm doing stuff in ACTION_MOVE and it's pointless to take event.getY()/ event.getX() , because they are the same. We're moving the shape(imageview).

Comment: @hugzhi you can try do this,because ACTION_MOVE doest  change event.getX(). Need to get view.getX() :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the coordinates like this , it will give you coordinates with reference to view not the screen.

```
                float xCord = event.getRawX()-v.getX();
                float yCord = event.getRawY()-v.getY();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there's no easy way of solving this if you want to really address the event within the bounds of the view. This is still occurring on Android Pie on some hardware. The only way to address odd touch events is to compare the last 3 events if there are no odd movements during ACTION_MOVE before rending the position of the view. Below is a sample when checking the event on a circular view. Assumption is that you created a **new double[3]** temporary variable :

```
  /**
     * This detects if your finger movement is a result of an actual raw touch event of if it's from a view jitter.
     * This uses 3 events of rotation as temporary storage so that differentiation between swapping touch events can be determined.
     *
     * @param newRotationValue
     */
    private boolean isRotationTouchEventConsistent(final double newRotationValue) {
        double evalValue = newRotationValue;

        if (Double.compare(newRotationStore[2], newRotationStore[1]) != 0) {
            newRotationStore[2] = newRotationStore[1];
        }
        if (Double.compare(newRotationStore[1], newRotationStore[0]) != 0) {
            newRotationStore[1] = newRotationStore[0];
        }

        newRotationStore[0] = evalValue;

        if (Double.compare(newRotationStore[2], newRotationStore[0]) == 0
                || Double.compare(newRotationStore[1], newRotationStore[0]) == 0
                || Double.compare(newRotationStore[2], newRotationStore[1]) == 0

                //Is the middle event the odd one out
                || (newRotationStore[0] > newRotationStore[1] && newRotationStore[1] < newRotationStore[2])
                || (newRotationStore[0] < newRotationStore[1] && newRotationStore[1] > newRotationStore[2])
        ) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```