# Why, when i get the coordinates of an image in android, it changes according to the device?

Tags: java, android

Why, when i get the coordinates of an image in android, it changes according to the device ?
@Override

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.monimage);
Log.d("", event.getX())
```

Why when i change of device, Nexus 4 prints 44 when i click on the sun of the image, and when I use nexus 5X, when i click on the sun of the image, it prints me an another number (77 for example) ?

Comment: because the 2 devices has different screen size and you are getting the X on the coordination system

Comment: and how to get the X of the image system, independant of the device ?

Comment: read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34062615/how-to-get-correct-coordsevent-getx-event-gety-of-object-with-ontouchlis

Answer (score 0):

event.getX() gives you the coordinates of the screen according to the your screen Resolution. For example, nexus 4 has 768x1280 and 5x has 1080x1920. So x and Y position will change according to the device resolution.